# Не знаю как выводить данные с консоли в поле Text в Tkintr

Tags: python, tkinter

Расскажите пожалуйста, как вывести данные с консоли в поле Text в Tkintr

Comment: уточните, какие данные требуется выводить ?

Comment: У меня есть программа которая считывает данные с Xml файла, эти данные должны выводится на экран в Tkinter, но я не знаю как это реализовать

Comment: text=Text(root)                text.insert(1.0, "всё что нужно")           text.pack()  вроде без ошибок.с телефона пишу.

Comment: спасибо, а вы еще не знаете как вывести данные но с другой программы ?

Comment: с другой программы из оперативной памяти ? или из эхешника на диске ? или просто чужой вывод считать ? пишите пожалуйста вопросы полностью, чтоб не приходилось задавать уточнения.

Comment: простите, из другой программы Python, перенаправить вывод с другой программы на питоне на основную программу питона с Tkintr

Comment: у меня есть две программы, одна на графическом редакторе Tkinter а другая парсит xml файл, в графическом редакторе есть кнопка которая запускает вторую  программу для парсинга. Вторая программа выводит данные в консоль но мне нужно что бы она выводил эти данные в поле Text в Tkintr

Comment: результаты парса можно сохранить в файл и патом считать его для вывода в ткинтере text это без проблем выведет со множеством строк

Comment: а как это сделать ?
не скажете как ?

Comment: https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/fajly-rabota-s-fajlami.html

Comment: а как вывести данные в ткинтер ?